# RANS in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: fluid-dynamics, coordinate-systems, flow, turbulence

Lets say we have a fully developed turbulent pipe flow. We consider the flow in cylindrical coordinates (x aligns in the streamwise direction). So $\bar{u_x}(r)$, we decomposition the flow as follow $u_r=u_r^{'}(x,r,\theta)$, $u_r=u_r^{'}(x,r,\theta)$ and $u_x=\bar{u_x}+u_x^{'}(x,r,'\theta)$.

The continuity equation, when the flow in incompressible, as follow:
$\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial ru_r}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial \theta}=0$. We decomposition it and take the average, but can we say: $\overline{\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial ru_r}{\partial r}}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial r\overline{u_r}}{\partial r}=0$? Because averaging is integrating just over time so all the other coordinates can be left out?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  But, you left out a 1/r in from of the theta component.

Comment: @ChesterMiller that looks like an answer.

Comment: @chestermiller You are correct. I forget the 1/r for the theta. But thanks for the conformation